Generate Spherical Harmonics without intermediate cubemap
I am in the process of generating Lightprobes using Spherical Harmonics.
The usual approach is to render a cubemap, convolve it to generate an irradiance cubemap and then sample it to generate spherical harmonics.
However, i would like to omit the usage of a cubemap (because rendering it would lock me into a specific Graphics API).
I am using Embree for my lightmapping process and intend to reuse it for Lightprobe generation.
When I trace into the scene, a ray would give me a single color value. Given a ray direction and the resulting sampled color - how would I generate a SH out of it?
public L2SphericalHarmonics[] Bake(in Vector3 position)
{
    // RGB
    L2SphericalHarmonics[] result = [new L2SphericalHarmonics(), new L2SphericalHarmonics(), new L2SphericalHarmonics()];
    for(int i =0; i < NumSamples; ++i)
    {
        // Fibonacci Sphere distribution
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/66257432/3001150
        var dir = MathC.PointFibonacciSphere(i, NumSamples);
        Vector3 sampledColor = RayTrace(dir);
        // somehow add to result?

    }
    return result;
}


With a ray direction and incoming light you can generate a cubemap without using any graphics api:
//for face +x
for(int y = 0; y < cubemapsize; y++){
    for(int z = 0; z < cubemapsize; z++){
        var dir = normalized(cubemapsize, y-cubemapsize/2, z-cubemapsize/2);
        Vector3 sampledColor = RayTrace(position, dir);

        outputImage.setpixel(y, z, toRGB(sampledColor));
    }
}

And so on for each of the 6 faces.

The question asks how to not use a cubemap. It's OK to post a "frame challenge" answer if you think the cubemap approach is more appropriate, but that answer should explain why the original goal of avoiding cubemaps won't work or leads to some undesirable scenario, in your assessment.
